# ubuntu 14.04 can not access some sites

Tags: 14.04, networking, internet, pppoe, dsl

I recently installed ubuntu 14.04 64 bit edition. I use PPPOE internet connection. But after configuring my connection I found that I can not access some sites like(twitter, odesk, download.opensuse.org etc.) I have checked related questions and tried to access these sites using different MTU. Before these installation I also used 14.04 but there was no problem. I upgraded it from ubuntu 13.10. New installation is causing these problem. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

try using a public DNS , because not accessing a site is due to not finding its ip address or not finding the server, so not accessing SOME sites means you can access others , so you internet access is good except that you are not resolving some names,
try using 8.8.8.8 , 8.8.4.4

Comment: yes tried this also. i am using these.

Comment: can u include the result of `nslookup twitter.com`